# How to declare encoding for all character columns in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, encoding, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters

Loading data from a package **on a windows machine**, encoding is botched.

```
require(vegdata)
tax_dbf <- load.taxlist("GermanSL 1.3", detailed=TRUE)
tax_dbf[33,"BEGRUEND"]
```

> [1] " "EinfÃ¼gen einer Zwischenebene""

I can fix that:

```
Encoding(tax_dbf$BEGRUEND) <- "UTF-8"
tax_dbf[33,"BEGRUEND"]
```

> [1] "Einfügen einer Zwischenebene"

However, I didn't manage to find an easy way to declare encoding for all character columns in the df, and my SO search foo is weak today as well. 
This is confuddling.

Anyone from the tidyverse having a oneliner for my prose?

Comment: this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24492969/apply-encoding-to-entire-data-table

Comment: ```dplyr::mutate(tax_dbf, BEGRUEND = Encoding(BEGRUEND)```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to use `tidyverse`. Just loop over columns that satisfy the condition:

```
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(a = rep("EinfÃ¼gen einer Zwischenebene", 5), b = runif(5), c = rep("EinfÃ¼gen einer Zwischenebene", 5), stringsAsFactors = F)

cols <- names(df)

for(i in seq_along(cols)){

  if(!is.character(df[, cols[[i]]])) next

  Encoding(df[, cols[[i]]]) <- "UTF-8"

}
```

Resulting in:

```
> df
                             a         b                            c
1 Einfügen einer Zwischenebene 0.2655087 Einfügen einer Zwischenebene
2 Einfügen einer Zwischenebene 0.3721239 Einfügen einer Zwischenebene
3 Einfügen einer Zwischenebene 0.5728534 Einfügen einer Zwischenebene
4 Einfügen einer Zwischenebene 0.9082078 Einfügen einer Zwischenebene
5 Einfügen einer Zwischenebene 0.2016819 Einfügen einer Zwischenebene
```

#### dplyr solution

```
dplyr::mutate_if(df, is.character, .funs = function(x){return(`Encoding<-`(x, "UTF-8"))})
```

Comment: Great. I failed on all ccounts, the '!is.character' and 'next' in the loop and the 'mutate_if' condition. The "return(`Encoding<-`(x, "UTF-8"))" for the function is and interesting way of thinking, what do these backticks do? Never done that.

Comment: You didn't fail at all, You had the right mindset, everybody is learning here For backticks discussion see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220823/what-do-backticks-do-in-r)